# Which trigonometric polynomials are identically zero?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

There are a number of elementary polynomial relations between functions of the form $\cos(nθ)$ and $\sin(nθ)$. For instance, $\cos^{2}(nθ) + \sin^{2}(nθ) - 1 = 0$, or $\sin(2nθ)-2\sin(nθ)\cos(nθ) = 0$. Such identities can be thought of as polynomials in $\cos(θ), \sin(θ), \cos(2θ), \sin(2θ), ...$

Is there a neat enumeration of *all* (or many) such polynomials? In other words, which trigonometric polynomials are identically zero?

Comment: $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$ is true if you replace $\theta$ with anything: $\cos^2n\theta + \sin^2 n\theta = 1, \cos^2 \sqrt{\theta} + \sin^2 \sqrt{\theta} = 1, \cos^2(\ln|\theta|) + \sin^2(\ln|\theta|) = 1$ and so on. This [meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34409/why-should-trivial-questions-not-meet-the-guidelines?cb=1) is about the exact same problem.

Comment: I do not think that there is an EASY classification of ALL such poylnomials.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the same question for the complex exponential functions $e^{in\theta}$ ($n\in\mathbf{Z}$) for notational reasons, then one can take real and imaginary parts and solve the problem for trigonometric functions.

The set of polynomials $p(e^{-in\theta},\ldots,e^{in\theta})\in\mathbf{R}[1,e^{i{\theta}}, e^{-i{\theta}},e^{2i{\theta}},\ldots]$ that are identically zero is an ideal.
One can write
$$p(e^{-in\theta},\ldots,e^{in\theta})= \sum_{N}\sum_{n_1+\ldots+n_k=N}\alpha_{n_1,\ldots,n_k}e^{iN\theta}=0$$
Since the latter is an equality between holomorphic functions valid for real $\theta$, it holds for every $\theta$. If there was an $N$ with $\sum_{n_1+\ldots+n_k=N}\alpha_{n_1,\ldots,n_k}\ne 0$, for lange imaginary $\theta$ you get a contradiction.

So $p$ is a combination of polynomials of the form
$$\sum_{n_1+\ldots+n_k=N}\alpha_{n_1,\ldots,n_k}\prod_{k=1}^je^{in_k\theta}$$
with $\sum_{n_1+\ldots+n_k=N}\alpha_{n_1,\ldots,n_k}=0$
A polynomial of such form is a linear combination of polynomials of the form
$$\prod_{k=1}^je^{in_k\theta}-
e^{iN\theta}$$
with $\sum n_k =N$.